# Wordpress SITE_URL and Visual Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables, visual-editor

I defined the global variables in `wp-config.php` as below

```
define('WP_SITEURL','/');
define('WP_HOME','/');
```

When "`define('WP_SITEURL','/');`" is defined, In admin panel, the visual editor is not woking. It is looking like disabled. Only the text editor part is working.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Changing the Site URL

> **Edit wp-config.php**
>
> It is possible to set the site URL manually in the `wp-config.php`
>   file.
>
> Add these two lines to your `wp-config.php`, where `example.com` is
>   the correct location of your site.
>
> ```
> define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
> define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
> ```

---

SRC: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Check the link above to see 3 other options for changing the **Site URL**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can't do it. Because my site should work correctly for any domain.